# Counting directories and files in bash

Tags: bash, loops

Simple counting dirs and files does not work. I am checking each file by -f and -d flag.

Where is a problem?

```
LOCATION=$1



for FILE in $(ls $LOCATION | egrep '^.{0,3}$'); 
do 
    echo "$FILE"
if [ -f $FILE ] 
then
    echo "its a file"
fi

if [ -d $FILE ] 
then
    echo "its a  dir"
fi

done
```

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Answer (score 1):

```
shopt -s dotglob # count hidden files

for file in "$LOCATION/"*; do
    [[ -f $file ]] && ((f++))
    [[ -d $file ]] && ((d++))
done

echo "${d:-0} dirs"
echo "${f:-0} files"
```

without involving external utilities